# Selecting sum of three consecutive values in a same row in the table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

plz refer the table to provide the sql query to get result like that.

```
id value
1  10
2  15
3  30
4  10
5  11
6  12
```

Desired output:

```
id  value
1   55
2   33
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21cbc8

Comment: Surely 'id' is nonsensical in this context

Comment: yes actually the real table dosn't exists the id column. is it possible to get the first and the last value in the group of three when we execute the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide id by 3, round it up, group it (with a `sum`):

```
SELECT 
    ceiling(id / 3) AS NewID, 
    sum(Value)      AS SumValue
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ceiling(id / 3)
```

With a variable:

```
SET @GroupVar = 3;  -- Set this number to whatever you want to group by

SELECT 
    ceiling(id / @GroupVar) AS NewID, 
    sum(Value)      AS SumValue
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ceiling(id / @GroupVar);
```

Comment: Suppose we do not want to fix the parameter as 3 we want a varriable at that place then is it possible to have a variable which can be changed time to time

Comment: thank you so much needed it. One more question is there. Is it possible to get the first element and the last element of the group of 3. by simply selecting by column name i can get the top element it the group but how to get the last element

for example in the first group we have 10, 15 and 30 
now how can we get 10 and 30 by query